# ASP.NET Core - making only one area as ANGULAR SPA application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, single-page-application

In past, with AngularJS I could create Partly Single Page Application. For example, mostly for the Admin panel, I had always created a SPA, but for the website itself was MPA.

Now I want to now, is there any easy way making one of the areas of ASP.NET Core MVC app as ANGULAR SPA?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: yes you can create all back-end  functionality in .net and angular you can user just front-end only

Comment: @harkeshkumar please read the question attentively. What am I asking and what is the your comment about.

Answer (score -1):

In the case you are developing for IIS use.
If you put a custom http module to run for all requests in the web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="RequestModule" type="MyWebapp.RequestModule" />
</modules>
```

You can tap the requests comming to the server and return your SPA for a specific subroute etc.

For more info see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms227673(v=vs.140))